# Python : Treating the key with None value as non-existant

Tags: python

In this scenario

```
>>> x = {}
>>> x.get('test') #Prints None
>>> x.get('test','') #Prints empty string
''

>>> x = {'test':None}
>>> x.get('test') #Prints None
>>> x.get('test','') #Prints None
```

How do I get empty string printed in both the cases by treating None valued key as non-existant ?

Comment: x.get(key,default_value) returns the value associated with the key. If the key isn't present it will return the default value. If you want the desired beahviour you would have to filter the dictionary first to remove None values.

Comment: something like ? `'' if not x.get('test') else x.get('test')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `get` call in a function that checks if the value is `None`

```
def get_except_None(d, key):
    val = d.get(key, '')
    if val is None:
        return ''
    return val
```

So instead of `x.get('test', '')` in your code, you would do `get_except_None(x, test)`